# He asked a lot of people for food. That meant/means he really needed it. - if the action just happened, do we use "meant" or "means"?

Tags: meaning, tense

**Example 1**

> He asked a lot of people for food. That meant/means he really needed it.

If the action of asking just happened, do we use "meant" or "means"?

**Example 2**

> He asked a lot of people for food. That showed/shows he really needed it.

If the action of asking just happened, do we use "showed" or "shows"?

Comment: Bet that both should be in present tense, as well as ‘needed’ should be ‘needs’ because he still needs food

Answer (score 2):

The question to ask oneself here is whether or not the verb's statement is still true at present (now), or is no longer true but was true in the past, or it no longer matters at the present time whether or not it is true (narrative past).

If the speaker is basing some evaluation or decision upon the present truth of this verb, use present tense.

- He asked a lot of people for food. That **means** he really **needs** it.

The reader or listener will infer that the person still needs food now.

- He (had) asked a lot of people for food. That **meant** he really **needed** it.

The reader may infer that he has already been given food now, and no longer needs it.  - OR - The context is one of narration of a story, now past.